# Can't install Subversion 1.6.17 on Mac OSX

Tags: svn

I'm installing subversion 1.6.17 on Mac OSX Snow Leopard.  I install it, then I go to a terminal and type "svn --version" and it still says "1.6.15".  Should I uninstall the old version first?  How?  Also as I'm going through the install, I do get a screen that says "Select a Destination", but it doesn't really let you do anything.  There is just the one option of "install fora all users of this computer", there is no way to select a destination. And the "change install location" button just takes you to the same screen.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered Git (http://git-scm.com/)?

Comment: @summea, what does Git have to do with this question? Suggesting an entirely different VCS isn't helpful in any way.

Comment: @KenWhite I've used both on Mac OS X and Git ended up being easier for me, at least.  It's a comment... not an answer. :)

Comment: @summea, you're right - at least it wasn't an answer. :) AFA being helpful, though... It's like "I need a tuneup on my Chevy. What does that cost?" and a mechanic saying "Did you consider a Ford instead?" - not really relevant or helpful. <g>

Comment: @KenWhite cars tend to cost money, however.  Software can (sometimes) be a little more flexible.  There is no reason given for why SVN is being used, here... and if it's not required (for a corporate environment or something,) suggesting another approach could be helpful... if only to point out that there are other version control options at present.

Comment: And Git requires the expense of time learning a new VCS. It doesn't matter what the reason is SVN is being used; the point is that it *is* being used, and an answer to a question about using it shouldn't be answered with "have you considered switching to another one?". :) I'm sure no one thinks that SVN (or any other VCS) is the only alternative available - maybe several years ago, perhaps, but now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you first uninstall the previous version so you can install the version 1.6.17.
 Maybe it's because the message that shows is that even configuration files have information about the version 1.6.15. I do not use mac os x, but in linux there are the ~ /.profile and ~ /.bash_profile that let you do that. I guess there are equivalent in os x. You can tell which version of subversion to your terminal runs the command 'which'

Comment: Thanks, yes, this was helpful.  The installer tells you where it will install ("/opt/subversion/bin"), and we were using svn from somewhere else.  Editing the .bash_profile (export PATH="/opt/subversion/bin/:...) fixed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I was about to warn you about what [appmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9487845/368630) said.

I took care of it this way:

- I created a directory `/usr/local/bin`
- I now create a symbolic link from each file in `/opt/subversion/bin` to `/usr/local/bin`
- In my `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, I redefine `PATH` to put `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` in my `PATH`. My Path is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:$HOME/bin`.

This way, if I want to override something in the `/bin` or `/usr/bin` folder, I can put it in `/usr/share/bin`.